# Shortening a read operation

Tags: variable, echo, read

This is my current `read` operation that works okay but I'd like to shorten:

```
echo "Please save your DB root password:" && read -s dbrp
echo "Please save your DB user password:" && read -s dbup
```

This is how I've tried to shorten it and quite failed (the prompt is important for me):

```
echo "Please save your DB passwords (root, then non-root):" && read -s dbrp && echo "\n" && read -s dbup
```

It is already in one line as I desired but I'm not comfortable with it because:

1. There are two `read -s` commands instead just one.
2. I must use `echo /n` to break row while I would want break without that.

Anything could be done to improve that?

### Update

I had a mistake using `echo` there (besides for adding `\n`. As `read` has its own prompt adding option:

```
read -sp "What's your DB root password?" dbrp
read -sp "What's your DB user password?" dbup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to change the name of your variables and make your code bash-specific (`-s` is available in `zsh` and `bash`; `-p` for prompt is `bash` only, `zsh` uses `read 'var?prompt'` like in `ksh` for that), I think the following is elegant and straightforward:

```
for arg in root user; do
    IFS= read -rsp "Please enter your $arg password: " "dbr_$arg"
    echo
done
```

The result should have your passwords in variables `$dbr_user` and
`$dbr_root`.

Note that [you need the `-r` and `IFS=` to allow the user to have backslashes or leading/trailing spaces or tabs in their password](/q/209123).

The `zsh` equivalent:

```
for arg (root user) IFS= read -rs "dbr_$arg?Please enter your $arg password: "
```

Comment: Hmm, using the `read` prompt via `-p` is cool. Argument `$1` is another argument `domain`, so I guess the `read` should relate to `$2` and `$3`.

Comment: `IFS`? `rsp`? What is the meaning of these?

Comment: @Arcticooling, see [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: @Arcticooling rsp is just the combination of r,s and p. It is just the same as `read -r -s -p`, and for these individual letters you can refer to the man pages